# How to time scripts thousands of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

beginner here.

My understanding is that `timeit` allows you to run code thousands of times and average the time it took. However, for entire scripts, I can't do that because there's going to be objects that `timeit` doesn't know about and/or I'm going to get an error because I put an entire script inside triple quotes. In that case I can use `datetime.now()` and subtract the start time from the end time.

However, this method doesn't allow you to run the code thousands of times and average the time; you can only run the code once at a time. Is there any way that I can average time entire scripts like I do small blocks of code with timeit?

Thank you.

Comment: Put the top-level code in a function, and then time that function.

Comment: You can call your `main()`

Comment: Would that still work if the script takes command line arguments? I'm getting
'''
  File "<timeit-src>", line 2
    data\structure2.txt
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
'''

where data\structure2.txt is the first of two command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Import the stript as a module using the if **main**... structure and simulate the arguments writing to the sys object (This will only be effective during runtime). Remember to call the python command standing in the folder of the script. An example code looks like:

```
import sys


def main():
    """
    Here you would put the spript that uses comand line arguments:
    """
    argument = sys.argv[0]
    print("The argument is: ", argument)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


## Then, standing on the script folder, to time the stript do this in python comand line:
# > import timeit
# > from timeit_with_script import main
# > sys.argv[0] = 10 # emulate your arguments
# > timeit.timeit(main, number=100) # run the benchmark
```

Comment: Thank you! 

Now I am getting >>> sys.argv[1] = 'data\structure2.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

. I would like to know how to do it this way, but if not, I did figure out how to do it from the script with stmt and setup arguments..

Comment: Write it as a vector : sys.argv = ["0", "some_text"]